# "rusty_v8" build error on 32-bit platforms

Tags: rust, v8, deno

I am new at Rust and Chromium V8 Engine.

I tried to build Deno from source on Raspberry Pi OS(32bit arm), but an error has occurred at rusty_v8 build. And same result on Intel 32bit.

```
  ../../../../.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1285ae84e5963aae/v8-0.39.0/src/binding.cc:40:1: error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'sizeof(v8::ScriptCompiler::Source) <= sizeof(unsigned int) * 8' "Source size mismatch"
  static_assert(sizeof(v8::ScriptCompiler::Source) <= sizeof(size_t) * 8,
  ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  3 warnings and 1 error generated.
```

I thought the size of "size_t" depends the host machine's architecture, so I fixed "binding.cc" to

```cpp
static_assert(sizeof(v8::ScriptCompiler::Source) <= sizeof(uint64_t) * 8,
              "Source size mismatch");
```

Is this correct? And please explain what is this "static_assert"?

I'm not a native speaker so please forgive my weird English.

Answer (score 1):

[Unforunately, Deno doesn’t have any plans to support 32-bit arm.](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/2295)

Comment: After I posted this question, I knew that Deno doesn't support 32-bit environments.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is this correct? And please explain what is this "static_assert"?

Static assertions specifically instruct the compiler to check that a certain condition is true, and produce an error otherwise. They are used to guard assumptions made by the code. So changing the `static_assert` without updating the code it guards is pretty much guaranteed to cause further problems.

In the case at hand, it is likely that some code assumes that a `v8::ScriptCompiler::Source` can be stored in the space of 8 `size_t`s. The static_assert makes sure that this assumption actually holds. By changing the assertion without updating the code that makes this assumption, you're very likely to create a bug (chances are, either something else will be overwritten, or a `Source` won't be fully stored; either way there'll likely be some form of memory corruption).

(If you want an analogy: it's like driving in a car and encountering a red stop light at a railroad crossing. You can "fix" it by throwing some green paint at the light, but unless you also stop the approaching train, that green paint is unlikely to actually help you :-) )

Comment: The analogy is useful! (although the idea of _throwing paint at lights_ is funny to me ).

Comment: The analogy makes it easier to understand. And I understand about "assert."
I knew v8 engine supports 32-bit envs but rust's bindings are not supported 32-bits after I posted this question. Thanks!